# js регулярные выражения - проверка на несоответствие конкретным значениям

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день. Есть js-код для проверки значения переменной с помощью регулярного выражения:

```
regEx = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,50}$');
if (regEx.test(value){
   // Делаем что-то
}
```

Есть ли возможность доработать регулярку так, чтобы она проверяла значение переменной на неравенство каким-то конкретным значениям (например *buh* и *buh2*). 
Пробывал как-то так:

```
regEx = new RegExp('(!buh)(!buh2)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,50}');
```

Но не работает.

Comment: На такой случай есть отличный инструмент https://regex101.com/ где можно посмотреть что попадает под регулярку, а что нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [негативным просмотром вперед](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%E5%E3%F3%EB%FF%F0%ED%FB%E5_%E2%FB%F0%E0%E6%E5%ED%E8%FF#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%91%D0%B4_%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4)

```
^(?!buh$)(?!buh2$)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,50}$
```

или так

```
^(?!buh\d*$)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,50}$
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/qUNmZ2/1